# Error while Call Sub in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am facing problem while calling sub. Error message is wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment. I tried many variations and nothing worked at all.

```
Sub last_non_empty_cell_in_a_row()

Dim rngCell As Range, i As Long

Set rngCell = Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=Cells(1, 1), LookIn:=xlFormulas, 
LookAt _
:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:= _
False, SearchFormat:=False) '.Activate
i = rngCell.Row

End Sub


Sub code_main()

Dim x As Long

Call last_non_empty_cell_in_a_row(i)

For x = 1 To i
If Range("R" & x) = "m_M" Then
If Range("P" & x) = "m_DH" Then
If Range("Q" & x) = "" Then
Else
Range("P" & x, "R" & x).Interior.ColorIndex = 22
End If
Else
Range("P" & x, "R" & x).Interior.ColorIndex = 22
End If
Else
Range("P" & x, "R" & x).Interior.ColorIndex = 0

End If

Next x



End Sub
```

Comment: You are passing `i` into `last_non_empty_cell_in_a_row`.  The Sub does not take a parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to change `last_non_empty_cell_in_a_row` to a `Function` and have it *return* the value of `i`.

```
Function last_non_empty_cell_in_a_row() As Long

Dim rngCell As Range, i As Long
Set rngCell = Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=Cells(1, 1), LookIn:=xlFormulas, 
LookAt _
:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:= _
False, SearchFormat:=False) '.Activate
i = rngCell.Row
last_non_empty_cell_in_a_row = i
End Function
```

And then, in the calling procedure:

```
Sub code_main()

Dim x As Long

For x = 1 to last_non_empty_cell_in_a_row()
...
```

There may be other problems or errors, I did not test. Notably, `last_non_empty_cell_in_a_row` seems to be a function signature that does not really describe what the function returns. For ways to get the "last cell" in a given range or sheet, see:

[Error in finding last used cell in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-vba)

Comment: Another option is to modify the Sub to accept a ByRef parameter.

Comment: Thanks! That was very useful and helpful. It is working fine. Anyway, converting it from Sub() into function() makes unable to call that macro separately, right?

Comment: @RafMil yes, you won't be able to call it like from the Macro menu.